# Does ObjectBox support FullTextSearch (fts)?

Tags: full-text-search, objectbox

I am wondering does ObjectBox support FullTextSearch (fts) for none-english, e.g Japanese, Korean, Chinese , languages?

If it does support, any suggestions as to how to do this in AndroidStudio?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `QueryBuilder.contains`([docs](http://objectbox.io/files/objectbox-java/current/io/objectbox/query/QueryBuilder.html#contains-io.objectbox.Property-java.lang.String-)) to search for text inside property values. There is no FTS indexing though at this time.